# how set a time period after which an event will close automatically in android eclipse?

Tags: android

i am a beginner. I am building an simple auction app in eclipse for my minor project. so i want to set a time period for bidding. after that time period the bidding for that particulate product will stop automatically. please help me with the code. i don't know what to do.

Comment: I am not an Android developer, but that sounds like a database question. If you are building an app that allows multiple apps to communicate you need a database for them to store users, auctions, bids, etc. If this is the case, I would recommend - if this is your first app - starting off with something that does not need a database. When it comes to any language, I find I learn better in stepping stones, so I don't overwhelm myself by trying to learn two technologies.

Answer (score 0):

You can decide yourself after reading [this aticle](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html).